# How to read json from local storage and display data in VUE

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a json(books.json) and I want to display its content into a list, on my webpage, with VUE.
I can't seem to succeed.
The code looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <span>{{items}}</span>
    <ul>
      <li v-repeat="items">
         <span class="name">{{books.name}}</span><br>
         <span class="genre">{{books.genre}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
 

<script>

    var app= new Vue({
        data: {
          items: null
        },

        created: function () {
          this.fetchData();
        },

        methods: {
          fetchData: function () {
          var self = this;
          $.get( 'books.json', function( data ) {
              self.items = data;
          });
          }
        }
    });
</script>
 
</html>
```

Can anybody help me please?
Thank you

Comment: This looks like a very old version of Vue (`v-repeat` should be `v-for`). Which version of Vue are you using?

Comment: Looks like you simply didn't include jQuery. Do you have that in your own code? Did you check the browser console for error messages?

Comment: Here's a fixed version without jQuery dependence: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vbeo6w5g/

Comment: I'm not aiming for a certain vue version, I will stick to 3.3.1 for the moment.
Even thought I addd the jQuery dependence, I still have the cross origin request error.
Thank you both, Chris and Decade Moon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your vue version. I've replaced `v-repeat` with `v-for` and mounted it to `#app`. You can also use `el` inside your vue instance instead of `$mount`. Additionally I've changed data to a function. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      items: null
    }
  },

  created: function () {
    this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      var self = this;
      
      // test data
      this.items = [{
        name: 'Test-Name',
        genre: 'My Genre'
      }];
      
      // Commented out because we don't have this file.
      /* $.get( 'books.json', ( data ) => {
        self.items = data;
      }); */
    }
  }
});

app.$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{items}}</span>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="book in items" :key="book.name">
      <span class="name">{{book.name}}</span><br>
      <span class="genre">{{book.genre}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
So I've updated my code,ant it looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ptny7r1s/
In mozilla I can't see anything and it chrome I get an error: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/ioana.mihailescu/standard%20vue%20project/books.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
Not sure if I understand correctly

Comment: This is a security policy. You cannot access file:// directly from your browser. Serve your file with a local server or upload it to one.

Comment: Your welcome! If this is the correct answer, you can mark it.